# Problema ao baixar dados do rbcb Banco Central no R

Tags: r

Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Estou tentando baixar dados de expectativas de inflação para um mes pelo pacote `rbcb`

https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/rbcb#market-expectations

Eu instalei e fiz o passo a passo para testar se esta tudo ok.

Mas quando eu chego aqui:

```
rbcb::get_monthly_market_expectations("IPCA", end_date = "2018-01-31", `$top` = 5)
```

Eu tenho essa mensagem de erro:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Pq será? O que esta faltando?

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Quando tentou baixar? Muitas APIs de bases governamentais ficam fora do ar em período eleitoral.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta ainda nos ultimos dias. Você tentou baixar? Conseguiu?

Comment: Não, mas parei de conseguir acesso ao DataSUS semanas atrás por esse motivo. Tem uma determinação do TSE que impede o acesso quando começa a propaganda eleitoral, aplica-se a várias bases, Não sei se aplica-se ao Banco Central, mas é uma possibilidade.